# Integrating HTTP / Webhooks with Message Queues

Tags: enterprise-architecture, message-queue, software-as-a-service, integration, rabbitmq

I'm working at a project which integrates several Applications mostly SaaS Applications. The SaaS solutions have all the possibilities to hook into the internal event system with webhooks. The webhooks give us the ability to send a message to a single system but we have to create multiple webhooks to send a single event so several systems.

My idea is to implement a message bus as a centralized middelware but the problem is that the SaaS solutions only provide an integration by http(s) and not with protocols like AMQP.

RabbitMQ for example provides the possibility to publish to a topic over http. To consume you can also use http but if the message is once consumed, the queue removes it or keeps it in the queue.

Has anybody a good solution to bridge the gap between http and aqmp? I thought about small consumer services which subscribe to a topic and then forwards the message to the RESTful API.

We try to avoid a huge enterprise service bus/iPaaS project currently. I know that this could be one of the best approaches but due to internal decisions and project time, costs and so on it's not a possibility for the moment.

One of our requirements is to have a guaranteed delivery, so that no message will be lost.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I don't see any problem with developing a service that implements a bridge from HTTP to AMQP, but it could spiral to become a quite large project. Seems quite large to get it right: https://medium.com/hootsuite-engineering/a-scalable-reliable-webhook-dispatcher-powered-by-kafka-2dc3d677f16b

Comment: Thought about kafka too but as you said, it could become a quite large project and I try to avoid a huge sideproject which builds the backbone of the communication.

Comment: My point is that as far as I know, there are no generic webhook implementations. And they are quite challenging to implement, so you are looking at a large project anyway.